# Sharepoint online Workflow CSOM or JSOM libraries for REST

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, cross-site

Are there any workflow activities that will build A REST request, and send it off to the correct location,  in the App Domain or in the Host-Web Domain.

I am running into an issue of trying to copy a file   using a REST call, but due to the Oringial server relative path and the  new path location being used  is  making my REST URL too long for sharepoint to handle.

I am able to complete this task using the JSOM  in my javascript but since there are a lot of files to be copy I would rather  send the task to a workflow allowing the user to leave the page and do other things then wait for my request to finish.

I was thinking about trying to use the

```
_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery
```

endpoint by building my XML myself but this seems like a very bad idea since my co-worker has told me that developing in this area is not supported.

Comment: Out of the box there is only "Call web service" workflow action, if you need copy file via workflow may be you look at the Plumsail Workflow Actions (http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/documents-list-items-processing/#CopyFile)

Comment: yeah that was what I was using to make the REST calls.  Sadly its either move the code to javascript and make the user wait or attempt to mimic the xml and send it to the processQuery function